# powerline9k zsh theme move vcs to left panel

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, powerline

Would someone help me configure my powerline9k theme for Oh My Zsh on my Mac. I am using Iterm2.

Following is my configuration so far.

```
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
POWERLEVEL9K_DISABLE_RPROMPT=true
POWERLEVEL9K_MULTILINE_LAST_PROMPT_PREFIX="▶ "
POWERLEVEL9K_MULTILINE_FIRST_PROMPT_PREFIX=""
```

And following is the output

[image]

how do I move the `git` part at the **right**.

Comment: There is [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/) now. It'll give you the same prompt but 10 times faster. It recognizes the same configuration options as powerlevel9k, so you won't have to change your config.

`git clone https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/powerlevel10k && sed -e 's/powerlevel9k/powerlevel10k/g' -i ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

First remove or set to false this line:

```
POWERLEVEL9K_DISABLE_RPROMPT=true
```

Then define in your .zshrc what features you want on the left and right side. For example:

```
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(vcs virtualenv vi_mode)
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status ssh dir dir_writable )
```

The `vcs` feature is what gives you information about a git or hg repository. An entire configuration in your .zshrc might look something like this:

```
# source /usr/local/opt/powerlevel9k@0.6.3/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='nerdfont-complete'
POWERLEVEL9K_VI_MODE_INSERT_BACKGROUND='005'
POWERLEVEL9K_VI_MODE_INSERT_FOREGROUND='236'
POWERLEVEL9K_VI_MODE_NORMAL_BACKGROUND='yellow'
POWERLEVEL9K_VI_MODE_NORMAL_FOREGROUND='236'
POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_GIT_GITHUB_ICON=""
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(vcs virtualenv vi_mode)
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status ssh dir dir_writable)
POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=truncate_to_first_and_last
POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH=2
prompt powerlevel9k
```

For further details on what "features" can be added to the prompts, see [here](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k#customizing-prompt-segments).

Comment: If I use this, I don't even see git branch

Comment: I've haven't provided an entire config, just the lines that control the right and left prompt.  You still need something `prompt powerlevel9k` at the end of your settings.

Comment: @GaurangShah, what specifically isn't working: (a) Moving the vcs to the left panel? (b) showing the git branch? (c) the font symbol for git branch not properly rendering?

Comment: Sorry for confustion..  I just want to move `VCS` to `Right` and that's the only thing now working.  I am able to see what I have posted in pic

Comment: @GaurangShah But, you've disabled the right prompt with: POWERLEVEL9K_DISABLE_RPROMPT=true, Remove that and add what I originally posted: both a RIGHT and LEFT prompt setting. Then inside the right prompt setting, add vcs.

Comment: @gergory Thanks... it worked.. like charm !!! is there a page where I can get what things I can show as a prompt

Comment: @GaurangShah, Yes! There are a lot knobs to fiddle with: https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k#customizing-prompt-segments  -- IMO, documentation is quite good.